# How to force reading docker-compose.override.yml file all the time?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say, I have `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-compose.dev.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` files.

If I am running `docker-compose up`, it parses configuration from `docker-compose.yml` and automatically overrides configuration by reading `docker-compose.override.yml`.

If I am running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up` it overrides with configuration from docker-`compose.dev.yml`,  but does not automatically read `docker-compose.override.yml` after that.

Is it possible to force docker-compose to add `docker-compose.override.yml` automatically if such file exists even if I provide the -f option?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment. If you use `-f`, it looks like you have to specify all of the files. How about creating a simple shell script that provides all of the required parameters (less typing).